# Find and print the biggest prime number (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, console-application

I'm studying node.js and have some interesting task - Write a program that finds and prints the biggest prime number which is <= N.

Input // Output - 13 // 13

126 // 113

26 // 23

In last course with java i have the same task and my code is really simple:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BiggestPrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();
        while(prim(n) == false){
            n--;
        }
        System.out.println(n);

    }


    public static boolean prim(int m){
        int n=m;
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
            if(n%i == 0){
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I try similar way to test it, but I'm don't have idea how to convert it:

```
let n = 126;

while (isPrime(n) === false) {
    n -= 1;
}
console.log(n);

let n = m;
for (let i = 2; i < n; i += 1) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Can you help me, because I'm really have problem with js using in console.

Comment: Your code looks right till `console.log(n);` statement, if you've defined the function `isPrime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You only need to declare a function and use it as you are doing.

```js
let n = 126;

while (isPrime(n) === false) {
    n -= 1;
}
console.log(n);

function isPrime(m) {
    let n = m;
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i += 1) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If your running it with NodeJS in console, you can save it in a file called prime.js (for example) and execute it with: `node prime.js`.

You can pass parameters to the script like: `node prime.js 126` and then get them in the code. That will be something like that:

```js
const args = process.argv;

let n = args[2];

while (isPrime(n) === false) {
    n -= 1;
}
console.log(n);

function isPrime(m) {
    let n = m;
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i += 1) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank's you very much.
This is what I'm looking for. In our learning "judge" for JS, we have commands for input gets() and pritn() for output.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. First off, you don't have `isPrime` defined. Second, if you were to paste all of your code into the browser console, it isn't going to like that you are defining `n` twice. I also cleaned up your `isPrime` bit of code.

```js
let n = 100;
let result = n;

const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num !== 1 && num !== 0;
}

while (isPrime(result) === false) {
    result -= 1;
}
console.log(result + " is the next prime below " + n);
```

Also, remember that javascript is not a compiled language, so unless you are defining your function in a class, the browser will interpret the code sequentially. Therefore, you have to have `isPrime` defined before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to find the nearest prime number can be further optimized. All prime numbers are of the form 6k+1 or 6k-1 except the numbers 2 and 3. Also, instead of checking all the way to the number the check can be made till Sqrt(n). Here is the modified isPrime function:

```
let n = 126;

while (isPrime(n) === false) {
    n -= 1;
}
console.log(n);
function isPrime(num) {
    if (num <= 1) return false;
    if (num < 4) return true;
    if (num%2 === 0 || num%3 === 0) return false;
    for (var i = 5; i*i <= num; i+=6) {
        if (num % i === 0 || num % (i + 2) === 0) 
            return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```